# gen_server handle_info/2 clarification

Tags: syntax, erlang, gen-server

While reading through Erlang and OTP in action, I ran across some weird syntax regarding records that I'm having trouble wrapping my head around. I'm hoping someone can clarify what's going on in the handle_info for timeouts here:

```
handle_info({tcp, Socket, RawData}, State) ->
    do_rpc(Socket, RawData), 
    RequestCount = State#state.request_count, 
    {noreply, State#state{request_count = RequestCount + 1}}; 

handle_info(timeout, #state{lsock = LSock} = State) -> 
    {ok, _Sock} = gen_tcp:accept(LSock), 
    {noreply, State}.
```

Specifically, I'm not quite sure what's going on here:

```
#state{lsok = LSock} = State
```

It appears to be some sort of reverse assignment? Are you effectively saying the second argument will be a #state record, to assign the lsock value to LSock variable and assign the whole record to State? I'm just inferring that from how the variables are used in the next two lines, but that syntax seems weird.

[EDIT]

I did some more testing of pattern matching and assignment in the shell, and it isn't working as I expected:

```
2> 1 = A.
* 1: variable 'A' is unbound
3> A = 1.
1
4> {1,2}.
{1,2}
5> {1,2} = B.
* 1: variable 'B' is unbound
```

Then I ran this test function to see if maybe it was just in matching function arguments:

```
test_assignment(A = {X,Y},{W,X} = B) ->
    io:format("Variable A is ~p~n",[A]),
    io:format("Variable B is ~p~n",[B]).


24> c(test).                              
test.erl:21: Warning: variable 'W' is unused
test.erl:21: Warning: variable 'Y' is unused
{ok,test}
25> test:test_assignment({1,2},{3,4}).
** exception error: no function clause matching test:test_assignment({1,2},{3,4}) (test.erl, line 21)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All function parameter definitions are *patterns*, and

```
#state{lsock = LSock} = State
```

is *one pattern* that binds State to the whole term passed as a function call argument, and at the same time asserts that it is a record state and binds State#state.lsock to LSock. In your shell examples,

```
A = 1.
1 = A.
```

are *match expressions*, which have the form

```
<pattern> = <expression>
```

and therefore, you may introduce and bind new variables only on the left hand side of "=". For an example that demonstrates a match with an equal sign inside the pattern, that you may run easily in an erlang shell:

```
1> ({X,Y} = Z) = {1,2}.
{1,2}
2> X.
1
3> Y.
2
4> Z.
{1,2}
```

On the other hand, your example with

```
test:test_assignment({1,2},{3,4}).
```

raises an arror, because in the function clause you defined X is used twice in the patterns {X, Y}, {Z, X} which cannot match arguments as obviously 1 does not equal 4. You might try in a shell:

```
5> TestAssignment = fun (A = {X, Y}, {W, X} = B) ->
5>   io:format("Variable A is ~p~n", [A]),
5>   io:format("Variable B is ~p~n", [B]) end.
6> TestAssignment ({1,2}, {3,4}).
** exception error: no function clause matching erl_eval:'-inside-an-interpreted-fun-'({1,2},{3,4}) 
7> TestAssignment ({1,2}, {3,1}).
Variable A is {1,2}
Variable B is {3,1}
ok
```

Note that a match expression returns rhs expression on match. You should now understand, why this works the way it does:

```
10> 4 = C.
* 1: variable 'C' is unbound
11> C = 4.
4
% 4 = 4, so this matches and returns 4:
12> 4 = C.
4
% now C is bound, so this is a match 4 = 5, not <anything, that will be bound to C> = 5:
13> C = 5. 
** exception error: no match of right hand side value 5
```

Comment: Ahh this makes sense now. I also didn't realize I had used X twice!

Answer (score 2):

Remember, "assignment" in Erlang is pattern matching. In the context given in your question,

```
#state{lsock = LSock} = State
```

asserts that `State` is bound to a value that is a `#state{}` record, and at the same time it binds the `LSock` variable to the value of the `lsock` field of `State`.

Comment: I guess I haven't seen unbound assignment on the right side of a pattern match. I would expect it to appear like this:

`State = #state{lsock = LSock}`

Comment: Remember that arguments to a function are already bound. So this code matches the `State` argument to a `#state{}` record construct and does the `LSock` binding at the same time. You can write it either way (try it!) but in my experience this order is more often used for arguments.

Comment: So I tried the reverse order assignment of unbound variables in the shell, and it isn't  working.

`2> 1 = A.

* 1: variable 'A' is unbound

3> A = 1.

1

4> {1,2}.

{1,2}

5> {1,2} = B.

* 1: variable 'B' is unbound`

Comment: That won't work because you're trying to match unbound variables. As I mentioned earlier, function arguments are always already bound, and that's the context for my "you can write it either way" comment. Try this in the shell for example: `1> F = fun(1=A) -> A; (A=2) -> A*2; (A) -> A*3 end.` noting how `A` is matched in either order in the first two clauses, and then `2> {F(1), F(2), F(3)}.` will return `{1,4,9}`.